# Discord.NET Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, discord.net

c# newbie here.

I'm trying to understand C# better through writing something interesting, like a discord bot.
What i'm trying is to have a seperate MessageHandler class to handle my messages.

Whenever i send a message though, i get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I'm not sure why this is happening, could anyone point me to the right direction?
I'll leave my code below.

//Program.CS

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        public static string token = "***";

        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        
        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _client.Log += new Logger().Log;
            
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();


            _client.Ready += OnReady;
            _client.MessageReceived += new MessageHandler().MessageReceived;
            
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task OnReady()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected as " + _client.CurrentUser.Username);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

//MessageHandler.CS

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class MessageHandler
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        public async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            
            var founder = message.Author.Username;

            if (founder != _client.CurrentUser.Username)
            {
                var channel = message.Channel;
                await channel.SendMessageAsync("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line in the code throws this exception?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if (founder != _client.CurrentUser.Username)

Comment: Did you debug your code ? Did you check if `_client` is null or `_client.CurrentUser` is null? If they are null that means you need to make sure that you assign value to them before using them.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a Discord Bot, you should only have **one** instance of a the `DiscordSocketClient`. The reason you get a null ref in your current code is because the `_client` variable in your `MessageHandler` is not connected/logged in to Discord and as such it does not have a `CurrentUser` (CurrentUser is null).

Take note of the code in your `Program.cs`

```cs
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        
    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await _client.StartAsync();
```

In this code, after creating an instance of `DiscordSocketClient` you call `LoginAsync` and `StartAsync`. This logs the "user" (bot) in and connects to the Discord Gateway. Once connected, this instance has a valid `CurrentUser`. However, when you got to your `MessageHandler`, you create a **new** instance of `DiscordSocketClient`, which does not get logged in. This second instance is **not** connected to the gateway and as stated about, `CurrentUser` will be null (and no, you don't want to login/connect a second client in the same application). What you should do is pass the `Client` created in your `Program.cs` to the `MessageHandler` and any other classes that would need to access the client.

As you are using Discord.Net, take a look at one of the [samples](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/dev/samples/02_commands_framework/Program.cs) available on the repo. There should also be some documentation for [getting started](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html)